# wordpress-develop unit testing couldn't fetch mysqli

Tags: wordpress, mysqli, phpunit

I've seen a lot of mysqli errors on stack overflow, but none seem to relate to wordpress-develop

I set up the test folder, bootstrap.php.

```
if ( function_exists( 'xdebug_disable' ) ) {
xdebug_disable();
}
if ( false !== getenv( 'WP_DEVELOP_DIR' ) ) {
require getenv( 'WP_DEVELOP_DIR' ) . '\tests\phpunit\includes\bootstrap.php';
}
if ( false !== getenv( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' ) ) {
define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', getenv( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' ) );
}
```

phpunit.xml

```
<phpunit bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite>
            <directory prefix="test-" suffix=".php">./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

config

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'bitnami_wordpress_testing' );
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

When I run a simple test

```
class test extends WP_UnitTestCase {
    public function test_foo_is_foo() {
        $this->assertTrue( 'foo' === 'foo' );
    }
}
```

I get the result along with a slew of warnings.

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
PHP Warning:  mysqli_affected_rows(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1760
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1812
PHP Warning:  mysqli_errno(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1708
PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Documents\wordpress-develop\src\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1735
```

I tested a couple basic methods and don't seem to be getting info from the database either. Not sure if there is any significance in the fact that the warnings are repeated. Does anyone with wordpress-develop experience know where this issue is likely coming from. Or perhaps anyone know of a better method/preferred tutorial for getting unit testing with wordpress up and running?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the warnings disappeared when I updated phpunit to version 6.5 (for testing with WordPress 4.9.4) whilst I was using version 5.0.* before.